# how to call a function from input string in java

Tags: java

how to call a function using input string in java,

actually ,i want to do this :

input given as a string : sin(44)+10+cos(10)

output : i want to get the answer to the input.

/*i am writing this to satisfy the conditions to ask a question so dont see below this line*/
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception

Answer (score 1):

You need to look for a math expression parser library.  Maybe something like this: [mathparser.org](http://mathparser.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt javascript interpreter.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ScriptException{
         Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);  
         System.out.println("Enter expression : ");  
         String expression = sc.next();  //Enter -> sin(44)+10+cos(10)

         ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
         ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
         String foo = "cos = Math.cos;" // ; or \n
                    + "sin = Math.sin;"
                    + expression; 
         System.out.println(engine.eval(foo));
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i do it in  java : i want to break the string and just recognise the substring is a function and call it and get the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try MathParser.org-mXparser.

site: http://mathparser.org/

tutorial:

http://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/

http://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/simple-expressions/

Code example to solve your problem

```
import org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser.*;
...
...
Expression e = new Expression("sin(44)+10+cos(10)");
double result = e.calculate();
```

Best regards